# Probability on entering direction of a simple random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $X(n)$ be a simple random walk on $\Bbb{Z}^2$. Also we define

- $S_{R} = \inf\{n > 0 : X(n) \notin [-R, R]^2 \} $ : the exit time of the square $[-R, R]^2$,
- $T_{v} = \inf\{n > 0 : X(n) = v\}$ : the hitting time of the lattice point $v \in \Bbb{Z}^2$,

I want to consider two conditional probability

$$ p(w \to v) := \Bbb{P}(X(T_v-1) = w \mid T_{v} < S_{R}). \tag{1} $$

In other words, I want to track the entering direction of my random walk when it hits $v$ before it hits the boundary.

[image]

Now fix $x = (a, b)$ in the open square $(-1, 1)^2$. Then $v = v(R) = (\lfloor aR \rfloor, \lfloor bR \rfloor) \in \Bbb{Z}^2$ and we can consider

$$ P(x, e) = p(v+e \to v) \quad \text{for} \quad e \in \{(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)\} $$

> **Question.** Does $P(x, e)$ converge to $1/4$ as $R \to \infty$ for any $e$? If this is the case, how fast the convergence takes place?

An ideal situation for my case would be that we have

$$ P(x, e) = \tfrac{1}{4} + \mathcal{O}_x (R^{-1}), \tag{2} $$

where the bound for $\mathcal{O}_x$ behaves quite well away from the origin and the boundary of the square. But my Monte-Carlo simulation seems to suggest that convergence would be slower, so I wonder if we have any tool to analyze this probability.

*Postscript.* I am also interested in the probability of 'last exit direction'

$$ q(v \to w) := \Bbb{P}^{v}(X(1) = w \mid T_{v} > S_{R}), \tag{2} $$

but this is easy to analyze for at least two reasons: it does not depend on the history, and the conditioning event holds with high probability. So I omitted this from my question.

---

**Addendun.** From numerical simulations with $R = 500, 1000, 2000, 4000$ and $x = (0, 0.5)$, I obtained the following log-plot for

$$(R, \textstyle \max_e |P(x, e) - 1/4|)$$

as follows:

[image]

So it seems not pessimistic to expect that (2) is actually true.

Comment: It suffices to show that unconditioned $P(X(T_v-1) =v+e)=\frac 1 4+O(R^{-1})$ and $P(T_v<S_R)=C+O(R^{-1})$ which looks easier.

Answer (score 3):

The $\frac14$ limit is of course true, but the conjectured error term seems to be off by a log; the first-order correction can be computed exactly using discrete potential theory. This post will not be self-contained; I refer to [these lecture notes](https://wiki.helsinki.fi/download/attachments/155233241/LectureNotes20_04.pdf?version=2&modificationDate=1430322536394&api=v2) for details on the background claims.

Given a function $h:\mathbb{Z}^2\to \mathbb{R}$, define its discrete Laplacian
$$
\Delta h(x):=\frac14 \sum_e (h(x+e)-h(x)), 
$$
the sum being over the four neighbours of $x$. If $\Omega\subset \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $v\in \Omega$, let $G_\Omega(\cdot ,v)\to \mathbb{R}$ be the Green's function, that is, the unique function satisfying $-\Delta G_\Omega(\cdot,v)=\delta_{\cdot,v}$ in $\Omega$, and $G(\cdot,v)\equiv 0$ outside $\Omega$. It is easy to see that if the random walk starts from $x$, then we have $$\mathbb{P}(X_{\tau}=v,X_{\tau-1}=v+e)=G_{\Omega\setminus\{v\}}(x;v+e),$$ where $\tau=\min\{t:X_t\notin\Omega \setminus\{v\}\}$. Also,
$$
G_{\Omega\setminus\{v\}}(\cdot;v+e)=-\frac{G_\Omega(v,v+e)}{G_\Omega(v,v)} G_{\Omega}(\cdot;v)+G_\Omega(\cdot,v+e),
$$
because the right-hand side satisfies the defining conditions of Green's function in $\Omega\setminus\{v\}$.

Now, we will plug in the above identity a family $\Omega_R$ of growing domains, so that the rescaled $\Omega_R$ converge: $$R^{-1}\Omega_R\to\Omega,\quad R\to\infty,$$ say, in the sense of Hausdorff. As explained in the lecture notes, if $h_R$ solves the discrete Dirichlet problem $\Delta h_R\equiv 0$ in $\Omega_R$, $h_R(x)=\varphi(xR^{-1})$ outside $\Omega_R$ for a continuous $\varphi$, then $h_R(Rx)=h(x)+o(1)$, uniformly over compact subsets of $\Omega$, where $h$ solves the (usual) Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ with boundary conditions $\varphi$. In fact, also all the "discrete derivatives" of $h_R$ converge to the corresponding derivatives of $h$

Moreover, as explained in the notes, we can construct the discrete full plane Green's function, or discrete analog of the logarithm: the unique function $G_0(\cdot):\mathbb{Z}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with the propeties $-\Delta G_0(\cdot)=\delta(\cdot)$, $G_0(0)=0$, and $G_0(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|+c+O(|x|^{-2})$ as $|x|\to\infty$. We can write
$$
G_{\Omega_R}(x,v)=G_0(x-v)+\tilde{G}_{\Omega_R}(x,v),
$$
where $\tilde{G}$ solves the discrete Dirichlet problem in $\Omega_R$ with boundary data $\varphi(x)=-G_0(x,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x-v|-c+O(R^{-2})=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log R+\frac{1}{2\pi}\log\frac{|x-v|}{R}-c+O(R^{-2})$. From the above remark on convergence of solutions to Dirichlet problem, we deduce that
$$
G_{\Omega_R}(x,v)=G_0(x-v)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\log R - c + \tilde{g}_\Omega(xR^{-1};vR^{-1})+o(1),
$$
where $\tilde{g}(\cdot,\hat{v})$ solves the Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ with boundary data $\frac{1}{2\pi}\log |\cdot-\hat{v}|$. Note that if $x$ and $v$ are at distance of order $R$ from each other, this can be written as
$$
G_{\Omega_R}(x,v)=g_\Omega(x,v)+o(1),
$$
where $g_\Omega$ is the Green's function of $\Omega$. What is more, the remark about convergence of discrete derivatives, together with symmetry of Green's function, implies that if $x$ and $v$ are at distance of order $R$ from each other and the boundary, then
$$G_{\Omega_R}(x,v+e)=G_{\Omega_R}(x,v)+R^{-1}\nabla_{2} g(x,v)\cdot e+o(R^{-1}),$$ where $\nabla_{2}$ denotes the gradient in the second argument. Plugging everything together, we arrive at
$$
\frac{G_\Omega(v,v+e)}{G_\Omega(v,v)}=\frac{-\frac14+\frac{1}{2\pi}\log R-c+\tilde{g}_\Omega(vR^{-1};vR^{-1})+o(1)}{\frac{1}{2\pi}\log R-c+\tilde{g}_\Omega(vR^{-1};vR^{-1})+o(1)}=1-\frac{2\pi}{4\log R}+O\left(\frac{1}{(\log R)^2}\right),
$$
and
$$
G_{\Omega\setminus\{v\}}(x;v+e)=\frac{2\pi}{4\log R}g_\Omega(x,v)+R^{-1}\nabla_2 g_\Omega(x,v)\cdot e+o((\log R)^{-1})+o_e(R^{-1}),
$$
where $o(\cdot)$ does not depend on $e$ and $o_e(\cdot)$ is allowed to depend on $e$. It follows that the event $S_R>T_v$ has probability
$$
\frac{2\pi}{\log R}+ o((\log R)^{-1}),
$$
and the conditional probability to exit through the move $v+e\to e$ is
$$
\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\log R}{2\pi R}\nabla_2g_\Omega(x,v)\cdot e+o\left(\frac{\log R}{R}\right).
$$

Comment: You say it's easy to see that

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{\tau}=v,X_{\tau-1}=v+e)=G_{\Omega\setminus\{v\}}(x;v+e)\;,
$$

but I don't see that. It seems to me that the right-hand side is the probability of reaching $v+e$ before leaving $\Omega\setminus\{v\}$; but the walk could still leave $\Omega\setminus\{v\}$ via the boundary and not via $v$, and the four neighbours of $v$ have slightly different probabilities of doing that?

Comment: @joriki, make a second copy $v'$ of $v$ that is connected only to $v+e$ (and assume that the original copy $v$ is connected only to the three other of its neighbors). Then, the probability on the left is just the discrete harmonic measure of $v'$, that is, it is discrete harmonic in the whole $\Omega\setminus \{v,v'\}$, with boundary values $1$ at $v'$ and $0$ elsewhere. Hence, if you now change the value at $v'$ to $0$ and identify it back with $v$, it will be harmonic everywhere on $\Omega\setminus \{v\}$ except at $v+e$, with the Laplacian at $v+e$ equal to $-\frac14$.

Comment: This is the definition of the Green's function; the $\frac14$ factor seems to be indeed missing.